# How to pass a dynamic value from textfield through the Yii2 kartik typeahead remote url

Tags: php, yii2, typeahead, kartik-v

I am using yii2 typeahead in my website like this

```
<?=$form->field($model, 'building',['inputOptions' => [
                  'autocomplete' => 'off']])->widget(Typeahead::className(),[
                  'name' => 'building_profile',
                  'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Type your building','class'=>'autocomplete','id'=>'building_profile','autoFocus'=>true],
                  'pluginOptions' => ['highlight'=>true,'autoselect' => true],
                  'dataset' => [
                        [
                          'datumTokenizer' => "Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value')",
                          'display' => 'value',
                          'remote' => [
                              'url' => Url::to(['sale-residential/all-buildings']) . '?q=%QUERY&country_id='.$country_id,
                              'wildcard' => '%QUERY'
                        ],
                          'limit'=>10
                        ]
                  ],
                  'pluginEvents'=>[
                    "typeahead:select" => "function() { getBuildingDetails(this.value); }",
                  ]
        ])->label(false);?>
```

This is my code.please have a look.There is a country_id in the url.And for now i am passing a static value to it.It is working now.But the problem is i want to pass a dynamic value from a textfield to that url something like

```
'url' => Url::to(['sale-residential/all-buildings']) . '?q=%QUERY&country_id='.{get the value from a text field with id my_country}
```

How can i do like this.Thanks in advance.My text field is in the same view file like

```
<?=$form->field($model,'country_id')->textInput(['id'=>'my_country')?>
```

Actually my need is, when i type in typeahead , i want to pass the user entered country id with the remote url.This is what i want

Comment: where is text field?

Comment: @InsaneSkull i just updated the question.Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `prepare` function in the `remote` array to read your textbox value, append the `url` with the `query` and dynamic value as a parameter. You can drop `wildcard`. Assuming your model is `SaleResidential`,

```
'remote' => [
    //// Typeahead query with dynamic value ////
    'url' => Url::to(['sale-residential/all-buildings']),
    'prepare' => new yii\web\JsExpression('function (query, settings) {
        // For the default textInput id
        settings.url += \'&q=\'+query+\'&country_id=\'+$(\'#saleresidential-country_id\').val();
        // OR For your custom textInput id
        // settings.url += \'&q=\'+query+\'&country_id=\'+$(\'#my_country\').val();
        return settings;
    }'),
],
```

See https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md#remote